# Each window resize event that appends a div with ajax, somehow creates an extra unwanted ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I set up window resize to create a div with an ajax call **and to remove the previously created div, if such one is found** (I tested it and no unwanted extra divs are actually created upon multiple resizing events -- **there is always just one div in the DOM**).

But when the ajax in that div fires, it fires the number of times I resized the window. I am not sure what could be the problem. It almost seems like the browser caches the created divs and, even though it keeps just the current div in the DOM, it causes the cached divs to trigger to the resize event. I disabled caching in the CMS.

I've tried adding a debounce function to the create_div function, as well as to the fire_ajax function - it didn't work.

```
var set_up_div = debounce(function() {

            if (window.innerWidth <= 767 && $('#mydiv').length == 0) {
                $('#mydiv').remove();
                $('#mydiv').prepend(mydiv);
            } 
            if(window.innerWidth > 767 && $('#mydiv').length == 0) {
                $('#mydiv').remove();
                $('#mydiv').prepend(mydiv);
            }

},500);     

var fire_ajax = debounce(function() {

              $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=extension/module/mycontroller/func1',
                type: 'get',
                beforeSend: function() {
                },
                complete: function(data){
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#mydiv').html(data);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'index.php?route=extension/module/mycontroller/func2&data={{somedata}}',
                            type: 'get',
                            beforeSend: function() {
                            },
                            complete: function(data){
                            },
                            success: function(data) {

                                $('#somediv').html(data);
                            }
                        });                 
                }
            });

}, 500);

function f(){
    set_up_div();
    fire_ajax();
}    

window.addEventListener('resize', f);
```

I need to be able to fire the ajax just once, even if window was earlier resized n times, but the more I resize the window, the more ajax calls are fired when the fire_ajax function is called, as seen in console.

Comment: Actually, I seemed to have gotten it almost solved. Phrasing the question prompted me to look for caching and I found that you can disable ajax caching. I disabled caching in all the connected ajax calls and now no matter how much I resize the page the div only fires twice. Not just once though, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: check how many times ajax is called?

Comment: the ajax in the div fires twice. I read an question on Stackoverflow about someone mentioning their problem with double firing, but I won't be able to find that question. It's ok though. Not too many fires won't matter much compuitation-wise in my case. EDIT: the ajax is called only once upon resize, plus one time when window ready function is called. Perhaps that's where the culprit is.

Comment: what is the necessity of calling ajax while window resizing?

Comment: the ajax is to place mydiv inside the left_column div or the content_top div, depending on screen size, and i have to have just one instance of mydiv on the page because i would have to write code to dublicate the values already filled in the form, which i didn't want to do.